# Saving transaction like header and detail using volley

Tags: android, android-volley

I am new for using `Volley` in `Android`. Now I want to save my transaction with these steps:

1. `Android` will call the service to get `RequestID` ( auto generated id from system ), then
2. `RequestID` will be used as one of parameter for any execution of detail transaction, then
3. If all detail transaction is successfully executed, go to another activity.

FYI : I use `ProgressDialog` for updating any progress for steps above.

My theory is like this:

1. I set message of Progress Dialog like "Sending your request to server", then
2. I use String Request to executed the header request, then
3. `onResponse` function of header execution, I get the Response ID from returned JSON, then
4. try to add to `RequestQueue` again of any detail transaction with specified param ( like `RequestID`, etc ) and
5. I also check if `onResponse` of any executed detail transaction if it is last detail transaction or not,
6. If it is last detail transaction, I try to dismiss Progress Dialog.

When I run the application, it stuck at second detail transaction ( I have 3 detail transaction ).

How can I set the sequence of `volley` request since I know that `volley` is asynchronous task, that can't predict the sequence of execution?

If you need the code, please let me know.

Thanks.